# QMessageBox does not destroy itself after selection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I have a thread that is running and a 'stop thread' button which when clicked calls a method that calls the terminate() of the thread. I have a QMessage Box that confirms the stop button before it terminates. The functionality is as expected but if I then start the thread again and click the close button then I get the confirmation MessageBox, I then select confirm and the thread stops but another confirmation box appears. It continues in this manner - if I run it 3 times I have to confirm three boxes, 4 I get 4 etc. The first box will terminate the thread in all cases. It seems like the MessageBox is not being destroyed properly each time it appears so they just build up? Not sure what's going on.

See below code. I have a thread 'my_thread' and a button connected to the function 'stop_thread' outlined below.

```
def stop_thread(self):
    prompt=QWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Stop!', 'Are you sure you want to stop thread?', QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes, QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
    if prompt == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
        self.my_thread.terminate()
    else:
        pass
```

I would expect each time I start and then stop the thread using the button I get one confirmation box appearing and upon selecting 'Yes' the thread will terminate. In reality the thread terminates but I get multiple MessageBoxes appearing one after the other - the number of them corresponds to how many times I have started the thread.

Comment: Please post a minimal example showing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it - It was because I was connecting the stop_button to the function outlined above in the function that I used to start the thread. So every time I started a thread I connected it again and called the function an extra time. What I didn't know was you could connect buttons to a function more than once (or multiple functions) but you learn something new everyday.

To fix I moved the connection of the stop button to the stop_thread function to the main class and now works great.